# python: reading and managing two related input text files

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have two .txt files; one represents the vectors I want to read (data.txt), and the other one represents the corresponding coordinates (coord.txt): Each line of data.txt represented by floats corresponds to a line of coordinates in coord.txt in x,y,z.

I want to do a couple of things; first, I would like to copy only a specified lines of data.txt according to their position in coord.txt. Second, in data.txt, every line of all zeros is not wanted therefore I don't want to copy it (I need to do this taking into account the position of each line specified in coord.txt).
For example data.txt:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1.2 3.4 5.6 4.4 2.0 4.5 1.1
2.3 4.5 6.1 3.3 2.3 6.5 7.1
3.4 2.2 5.1 4.3 3.3 6.5 8.0
1.1 2.6 7.2 1.9 7.9 9.4 3.7 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
2.3 5.6 4.1 6.8 9.3 2.5 7.5
1.1 4.5 3.2 5.7 8.5 3.5 5.4
```

coord.txt:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
1 4 0
1 0 0
1 1 0
4 1 1
0 4 0
0 16 1
```

In this case the first line of data.txt is not to be copied (same for its corresponding position in coord.txt). Also, I would like to save vectors that correspond to coordinates that have the x or y component that are multiple of 4 (eg x or y = 0,4,8,12, 16 etc.. and z can be whatever).

```
 def not_zeroes(arr):
    return any([x!=0 for x in arr])


with open('data.txt') as data, open('coord.txt') as coordinates: 
    for x,y in izip(data, coordinates):
        numbers= map(float,x.split())
        positions =map(int, y.split())
        if coord[y][0]%4==0 and coord[y][1]%4==0 and not_zeroes(numbers):
            vectors.append(numbers)
            coord.append(positions)
```

This is the error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made some mistakes. You need to check first and second element of positions, not the original strings.

```
def not_zeroes(arr):
    return any([a != 0 for a in arr])

with open('data.txt', 'rb') as data, open('coord.txt', 'rb') as coordinates:
    for x, y in zip(data, coordinates):
        numbers = map(float, x.split())
        positions = map(int, y.split())
        if (positions[0] % 4 == 0 and positions[1] % 4 == 0) and not_zeroes(numbers):
            vectors.append(numbers)
            coord.append(positions)
```

If running your example it's going to give the expected result:

```
[1.2, 3.4, 5.6, 4.4, 2.0, 4.5, 1.1] [0, 0, 1]
[2.3, 5.6, 4.1, 6.8, 9.3, 2.5, 7.5] [0, 4, 0]
[1.1, 4.5, 3.2, 5.7, 8.5, 3.5, 5.4] [0, 16, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error is being caused by how you are getting and using `x` and `y`.

The line `for x,y in izip(data, coordinates):` is probably setting the variables as strings, so they can't be used as indices in the following line

```
if coord[y][0]%4==0 and coord[y][1]%4==0 and not_zeroes(numbers):
```